# Show my application in share dialog

Tags: react-native

In `React Native` how is it possible to add application to the list of applications shown in the share list. e.g. when I want to share a pic it suggests some applications, I want my app to be in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-share-extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension).